# Specifying install location from commandline packagemaker

Tags: macos, installation, packagemaker

Being new to packagemaker I assume I am just missing something. It does not seem all the options in the GUI are available from the command line. I have read the man page but maybe I just don't get it.

Of most interest to me is how do I specify the install locations of the files?

From the commandline to I need to also use installer in combination with packagemaker to get the same results of the GUI packagemaker? If so are there any examples you can recommend?

Thanks
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing to change the install directory from command line:

- create the package
- extract the new package with pkgutil
- string search for `install-location="/"` in the pkg file's PackageInfo, replace with desired install location
- repackage with pkgutil

That works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating packages using commandline mode of packagemaker, you will have to create a  dummy directory which contains all your files in proper location. For example, if you have to install files `A` and `B` at `/Library/Applications/` and `/Library/Application Support/` respectively, then you create the structure as below.

Create a temp directory, say `SourceFiles`.
Add your files to this directory as follows-

```
SourceFiles/Library/Applications/A
SourceFiles/Library/Application Support/B
```

Now use the flag --root in packagemaker commandline mode.

```
packagemaker --root SourceFiles/ OTHER_OPTIONS
```

The idea is that instead of passing location of individual files to the command, you create a similar structure in a temporary directory and just pass that directory as argument to --root flag.

More for commandline mode of packagemaker:
http://macinstallers.blogspot.in/